# does the existence of an asterisk in a select exclude other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This question is all about laziness... I'd like to do something like this:

```
select some_func(some_col), * from my_table
```

So that I don't have to do this:

```
select some_func(some_col), col_1, col_2... col_ad_infinitum from my_table
```

Is there any way to make the first query work?  This is the error I get when I run it:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from my_table' at line 1
```

Comment: The first query should run just fine as-is.  Are you meaning you want `some_col` to be left out from the `*` part of the query?  If so, no you cannot do that.  It's a well-debated issue, and the only *lazy* approach is to use dynamic SQL to generate the list of columns in the query.

Comment: Your first query should work. Did you try it?

Comment: what is the goal of the Select? What does it do? Does it return data to an application? a report? If you change my_table, your query will now return more columns than before and that tends to screw up stuff. It's a bug just waiting to happen.

Comment: I do not understand how generation of a select with dynamic sql is considered lazy.

Comment: *Lazy* instead of (not lazy) typing of 50 column names :)

Comment: @mellamokb: the first query does not run as-is. It produces error, in both 5.1 and 5.5 versions of MySQL.

Comment: @Stephanie: IMO, automation is always lazier than doing things by hand, even if setting up the automation takes way longer.  It's a perspective thing I guess :-)

Comment: @mellamokb Wasn't sure if you meant it as a good thing or bad. I've written a customer query in my IDE so when I right click on a table, I can have it return the columns concat with commas. Lazy yes, but in a good, programmer way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean that in MySQL your first query:

```
SELECT some_func(some_col), * 
FROM my_table
```

produces this error?:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*' at line 1

---

You can change your code into (this results in no errors!):

```
SELECT *, some_func(some_col) 
FROM my_table
```

or into this, if you want to have the calculated columns first:

```
SELECT some_func(some_col), t.* 
FROM my_table AS t
```

Comment: Any suggestion why MySQL throws an error here? The FROM clause should be clearly enough to decide what table I meant there...

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, mysql only supports the asterisk at the *start* of the column list (unlike every other DB I am familiar with)

(Edited: *start* not *end* - oops!)

Comment: You mean at the start, not at the end.

Comment: That's probably because every other DB you are familiar with cannot reference previous select fields in the same query like mysql can :-)

Comment: @mellamokb: What do you mean? Can you give an example of a query with such reference that works in MYSQL?

Comment: In MYSQL, you can do something like `select 1 as myval, myval + 2 as myval2`, where the `myval` in the second field is a direct reference to the output value of the first field.  I know you can't do this in SQL Server, but I'm not sure about other DB systems.

Comment: That seems dangerous. What if there is also a column in one of the tables called myval? I hope in that case the query just fails with an ambiguous reference...

Comment: @mellmokb: It's not only dangerous but not in SQL standards. I can't test now but I seriously doubt you can actually do that in MySQL. You probably mean using variables. (`@myval`).

Comment: @ypercube: Ya actually it looks like you're right (tested on sqlzoo.net).  I think I was thinking MS Access, which does allow you to refer to previous fields - but also has no problem with an `*` showing later in the field list... go figure!

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of your select params:

```
select *,some_func(some_col) from my_table
```

Anyway, as the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says: "Explicit is better than implicit". Always try to write the fields you're selecting, and if it's posible try to put the table they're from too, you can use an alias. Your future YOU will thank you.

```
select t.some_col from my_table t
```

Answer (score 0):

When I do that with PostgreSQL, I get the column(s) I specify followed by all the other columns (possibly repeating the column(s) I specified).