# Does "*" ensure a specific column ordering?

Tags: sql, database

I'm curious about a query I saw written "by a friend" (LOL) and I was surprised by it. Here's the simplified case:

```
create table my_table (
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  d int,
  primary key (a, b, c)
);

insert into my_table (a, b, c, d) values (1, 2, 3, 4);
insert into my_table (a, b, c, d) values (5, 6, 7, 8);

select *, count(*), sum(d)
from my_table
group by 1, 2, 3
```

This actually works in PostgreSQL, and translates in the last line `1, 2, 3` to `a, b, c`, and never to `c, b, a` or other.

Result (PostgreSQL 11.1):

```
a  b  c  d  count  sum
-  -  -  -  -----  ---
5  6  7  8      1    8
1  2  3  4      1    4
```

So, does `*` actually *preserve* column ordering?

I won't probably write a confusing query like this ever, but still wanted to know if the SQL Standard said anything about it.

Comment: This does NOT work in Postgres -- and I would think you would know that -- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2f5eab2719cc470cf9d9e5a8d15a02e3.

Comment: 2 things: 1, this errors. 2, I believe the `*` just expands to the columns based on ordinal. So I think it would keep order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: it works if the columns include the primary key: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e3b18892572cda42c4f9752765dac39d

Comment: Added the primary key definition and now it works everywhere.

Comment: @GSerg Perfect. "...The columns are referenced in the ascending sequence of their ordinal position within T...". That answers it clearly. Please mark as duplicate to close.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have.

Comment: Syntax error. A single `*` must be alone in the select list.

Comment: @jarlh Why? You can add other things after a comma. You can click the dbfiddle links in [comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992091/does-ensure-a-specific-column-ordering#comment106097345_59992091) and see it working.

Comment: @GSerg, ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), 7.16 <query specification> "<query specification> ::=
SELECT [ <set quantifier> ] <select list> <table expression>", "
**<select list> ::=
<asterisk>**
| <select sublist> [ { <comma> <select sublist> }... ]".

Comment: @jarlh And then `<select sublist> ::= <derived column> | <qualifier> <period> <asterisk>`. Which sometimes results in [`select something_else, *` not working but `select *, something_else` working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7575443/11683), and sometimes [requires the alias before the `.*` anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2319679/11683). It is a fact that `select *, something_else` works in [e.g. PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992091/does-ensure-a-specific-column-ordering#comment106097345_59992091), or e.g. SQL Server, or e.g. MySql.

Comment: @GSerg, yes, I know. It seems to work with _most_ dbms products, Oracle and a few others excluded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore your example code and address the question:

> Does `*` actually preserve column ordering?

In general, I have not found specific documentation or reference that the column ordering is guaranteed to be preserved.  I would be very happy if someone produced such a reference, either in the standard or even in a particular database.

However, I think it is safe to assume that the ordering is preserved.  Following are three reasons.

The first is that all databases that I have experience with have always preserved the ordering.  Even more, for multiple tables the ordering is in the ordering specified in the `FROM` clause.

Second is that the ordering is known -- at least in databases that provide metadata schemas.  The column `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_NUMBER` has this information.

And finally, the following works and I think is guaranteed to work in any database:

```
insert into t
    select *
    from t;
```

In order for this to work, the columns need to be in the specified order.  I don't think a `SELECT` can behave differently in an `INSERT . . . SELECT` than it would by itself (other than the order of the rows).

Comment: `I would be very happy if someone produced such a reference` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11737363/11683?

Comment: ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), 7.16 <query specification>, 4)B, "_Otherwise, the <select list> “*” is equivalent to a <value expression> sequence in which each <value
expression> is a column reference that references a column of T and each column of T is referenced
exactly once. The columns are referenced in the ascending sequence of their ordinal position within
T._"